# bootstrap menu collapse but not showing on clicking on collapsed button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using **bootstrap** and have a simple menu with two items

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="item1.html">item2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script></body></html>
```

1) When the browser is expanded I see buttons `item1`, `item2` on the right side and it's working well

2) When the width of the browser is smaller, menu is collapsed
[collapsed menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wPfJ.png)

3) But, after clicking on the menu button, `item1` and `item2` are not shown.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: bootstrap.js is added, I've just put part of the code. Menu is collapsing so bootstrap is working. jquery is also added before bootstrap

Comment: Please create a working example like on Fiddle so that we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the jquery and the bootstrap js in the html. They are required for the navigation to work in responsive mode?
If not, try adding both of them in the html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You need to import/add first the jquery and then the bootstrap js, because bootstrap js is dependent of the jquery.

Comment: Can you open the source of the page in the browser and try to open both js with the links from there? Do you get any error messages in the console of the browser?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I was linking to jquery.js and bootstrap.js but on the disk I have jquery_min.js and bootstrap_min.js

Comment: No problem. Glad you resolve the problem. Please accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot

I was linking to wrong *.js files :(

I didn't see any error, so I thought path were correct.